# Compare 2 Tables When 1 Is Null in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, null, left-join, grouping, counting

1. List item

I am kinda new in PostgreSQL and I have difficulty to get the result that I want.
In order to get the appropriate result, I need to make multiple joins and I have difficulty when counting grouping them in one query as well.

The table names as following: pers_person, pers_position, and acc_transaction.
What I want to accomplish is;

1. To see who was absent on which date comparing pers_person with acc_transaction for any record, if there any record its fine... but if record is null the person was definitely absent.
2. I want to count the absence by pers_person, how many times in month this person is absent.
3. Also the person hired_date should be considered, the person might be hired in November in October report this person should be filtered out.
4. pers_postition table is for giving position information of that person.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
SELECT tr.create_time::date AS Date, pers.pin, tr.dept_name, tr.name, tr.last_name, pos.name, Count(*)
FROM acc_transaction AS tr
RIGHT JOIN pers_person as pers
ON tr.pin = pers.pin
LEFT JOIN pers_position as pos
ON pers.position_id=pos.id
WHERE tr.event_no = 0 AND DATE_PART('month', DATE)=10 AND DATE_PART('month', pr.hire_date::date)<=10 AND pr.pin IS DISTINCT FROM tr.pin
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

*This is report for octeber, 
*Pin is ID number

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by

- changing the `RIGHT JOIN` for a `LEFT JOIN` as they works the same in reverse but it's confusing to figure them both in mind :
- removing for now the `pers_position` table as it is used for added information purpose rather than changing any returned result
- there is an unknown alias `pr` and I'd assume it is meant for `pers` (?), changing it accordingly
- that leads to strange WHERE conditions, removing them
- - "pers.pin IS DISTINCT FROM pers.pin" (a field is never distinct from itself)
- - "AND DATE_PART('month', DATE)=10 " (always true when run in october, always false otherwise)

Giving the resulting query :

```
SELECT tr.create_time::date AS Date, pers.pin, tr.dept_name, tr.name, tr.last_name, Count(*)
FROM pers_person as pers
LEFT JOIN acc_transaction AS tr ON tr.pin = pers.pin
WHERE tr.event_no = 0 
    AND DATE_PART('month', pers.hire_date::date)<=10 
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

At the end, I don't know if that answers the question, since the title says "Compare 2 Tables When 1 Is Null in PostgreSQL" and the content of the question says nothing about it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I run the query you provided and got error with GROUP BY ''''''''''''''''' ERROR:  column "pers.pin" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: SELECT tr.create_time::date AS Date, pers.pin, tr.dept_name,...
                                             ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 39            '''''' when i remove GROUP BY and COUNT it works